# Linear Algebra - Why is x hat in the row space in least squares

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

Why is x hat in the row space? I understand why e is in the left nullspace, I understand why p is in the column space, I get why the nullspace is 0 (given indpendepent columns), but I dont understand why x hat is in the rowspace...

The problem is as follows: Which of the four subspaces contains the error
vector e? Which contains p? Which contains xˆ? What is the nullspace of
A?
This is all regarding a least squares projection where p is the projected vector, e is error vector, and x hat is the vector in which Axhat = p.

Comment: You need to give more context about the setup of your least squares problem. (What is $\hat{x}$? What is $p$? Row space and column space of what matrix?)

Comment: Just added the problem

Comment: If $A$ has $m$ rows and $n$ columns with $m\ge n$, and the columns are independent, then the rank is $n$, so the rows span ${\bf R}^n$, so every element of ${\bf R}^n$ is in the rowspace. In particular, $\hat x$.

Comment: Does that answer your question, vmuse?

Comment: Please enage, vmuse.

Comment: Yes, does answer my question!